# How to execute raw query in jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb, mongodb-query, jenssegers-mongodb, laravel-mongodb

I'm looking to make a query that gets all the existing indexes of a collection.

I have tried the following code:

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoDB()->execute("db.registrations.getIndexes()")
```

But getting error

```
Call to undefined method MongoDB\Database::execute()
```

How do I execute raw queries on this library?

Thanks

Comment: Did you got the answer